# Multiple Spinner in one activity with different table in phpmyadmin

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm creating an application that needs multiple spinners. The data on the spinners will come from phpmyadmin but in different table. For example, spinner for storecodes and spinner for banks just like in my application. Now let's say that the table for storecodes have 15 items and the table for banks only have 10 items, they parse just fine. But the problem is if I click one of the 11-15 items in storecode spinner, it crashes. They work fine if the table does have the same number of items but crashes if one table have more than 1 item. What should I do with my codes?

Code for Java file

```
public class DailySales extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    ArrayList<String> banknames=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> storecodes=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1, adapter2, adapter3, adapter4, adapter5;
    String storecode, spinner2, spinner3, spinner4, spinner5;
    TextView TVCash, TVCredita, TVCreditb, TVDebita, TVDebitb, TVEcpv, TVGc, TVSd, Salesdate;
    EditText Cash, CreditA, CreditB, DebitA, DebitB, Ecpv, Gc, Sd;
    Spinner Storecode, Spinner2, Spinner3, Spinner4, Spinner5;
    Button submit;
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_sales);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(drawer);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        NavigationView navigationView=(NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        Cash = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cash);
        CreditA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.credita);
        CreditB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.creditb);
        DebitA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.debita);
        DebitB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.debitb);
        Ecpv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ecpv);
        Gc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gc);
        Sd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sd);

        Salesdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.salesdate);

        TVCash = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewcash);
        TVCredita = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewcredita);
        TVCreditb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewcreditb);
        TVDebita = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewdebita);
        TVDebitb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewdebitb);
        TVEcpv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewecpv);
        TVGc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewgc);
        TVSd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewsd);

        Storecode = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.storecode);
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,storecodes);
        Storecode.setAdapter(adapter1);
        Storecode.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,banknames);
        Spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        Spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,banknames);
        Spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);
        Spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        adapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,banknames);
        Spinner4.setAdapter(adapter4);
        Spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
        adapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,banknames);
        Spinner5.setAdapter(adapter5);
        Spinner5.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Salesdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(DailySales.this, R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Salesdate.setText(year+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+dayOfMonth);
                    }
                }, year,month,day);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DailySales.this);
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure about the informations?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (Salesdate.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                                    Salesdate.setError("Pick a date");
                                } else if (Cash.length() == 0 && CreditA.length() == 0 && CreditB.length() == 0
                                        && DebitA.length() == 0 && DebitB.length() == 0 && Ecpv.length() == 0 &&
                                        Gc.length() == 0 && Sd.length() == 0){
                                    opendialog();
                                } else {
                                    dailysales();
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void opendialog(){
        ExampleDialog exampleDialog = new ExampleDialog();
        exampleDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "example dialog");
    }

    public void dailysales(){
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "(I will not show the url)", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(response.contains("1")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DailySales.class));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Added Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if(response.contains("2")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data does not added successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                //DATE PICKER
                params.put("salesdate",Salesdate.getText().toString());
                //SPINNERS
                params.put("storecode",Storecode.getSelectedItem().toString());
                params.put("spinner2",Spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
                params.put("spinner3",Spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString());
                params.put("spinner4",Spinner4.getSelectedItem().toString());
                params.put("spinner5",Spinner5.getSelectedItem().toString());
                //TEXT VIEWS
                params.put("tvcash",TVCash.getText().toString());
                params.put("tvcredita",TVCredita.getText().toString());
                params.put("tvcreditb",TVCreditb.getText().toString());
                params.put("tvdebita",TVDebita.getText().toString());
                params.put("tvdebitb",TVDebitb.getText().toString());
                params.put("tvecpv",TVEcpv.getText().toString());
                params.put("tvgc",TVGc.getText().toString());
                params.put("tvsd",TVSd.getText().toString());
                //EDIT TEXTS
                params.put("cash",Cash.getText().toString());
                params.put("credita",CreditA.getText().toString());
                params.put("creditb",CreditB.getText().toString());
                params.put("debita",DebitA.getText().toString());
                params.put("debitb",DebitB.getText().toString());
                params.put("ecpv",Ecpv.getText().toString());
                params.put("gc",Gc.getText().toString());
                params.put("sd",Sd.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }
        };
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
    }

    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        BackTask bt=new BackTask();
        bt.execute();
    }

    private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ArrayList<String> list1;
        ArrayList<String> list2;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            list1 = new ArrayList<>();
            list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            InputStream is1 = null;
            InputStream is2 = null;
            String result1 = "";
            String result2 = "";
                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("(I'm aware about the url)");
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is1 = entity.getContent();

                    HttpClient httpClient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost2 = new HttpPost("(I'm aware about the url)");
                    HttpResponse response2 = httpClient2.execute(httpPost2);
                    HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
                    is2 = entity2.getContent();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1, "utf-8"));
                    String line1 = "";
                    while ((line1 = bufferedReader1.readLine()) != null) {
                        result1 = line1;
                    }
                    is1.close();

                    BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is2, "utf-8"));
                    String line2 = "";
                    while ((line2 = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null) {
                        result2 = line2;
                    }
                    is2.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray(result1);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                        list1.add(jsonObject1.getString("storecode"));
                    }
                    JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray(result2);
                    for (int ii = 0; ii < jsonArray2.length(); ii++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(ii);
                        list2.add(jsonObject2.getString("bank_name"));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            storecodes.addAll(list1);
            banknames.addAll(list2);
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter4.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter5.notifyDataSetChanged();

            List<String> Storecodes = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(storecodes));
            Storecode.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DailySales.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Storecodes));

            List<String> Banknames1 = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(banknames));
            Spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DailySales.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Banknames1));

            List<String> Banknames2 = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(banknames));
            Spinner3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DailySales.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Banknames2));

            List<String> Banknames3 = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(banknames));
            Spinner4.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DailySales.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Banknames3));

            List<String> Banknames4 = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(banknames));
            Spinner5.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DailySales.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Banknames4));

            Collections.sort(storecodes);
            Collections.sort(banknames);
            Collections.sort(banknames);
            Collections.sort(banknames);
            Collections.sort(banknames);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        storecode = Storecode.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        spinner2 = Spinner2.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        spinner3 = Spinner3.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        spinner4 = Spinner4.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        spinner5 = Spinner5.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
}
```

This is the error in the logcat

```
@Erythrozyt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.(package name), PID: 29660
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:385)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(AdapterView.java:798)
        at com.example.(package name).onItemSelected(DailySales.java:392)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:944)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:933)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:898)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:187)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7025)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:514)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888
```

Comment: Please post the Kind of Exception which is thrown

Comment: @Erythrozyt what do you mean Kind of Exception?

Comment: The Error which is thrown. Maybe an IndexOutOfBoundException or NullPointerException, etc.